# Regex for matching alphabet, numbers and special charters while looping in python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to find words and print using below code. Everything is working perfect but only issue is i am unable to print the last word(which is number).

```
words = ['Town of','Block No.','Lot No.','Premium (if any) Paid ']

import re
for i in words:
    y = re.findall('{} ([^ ]*)'.format(i), textfile)
    print(y)
```

Text file i working with:

```
textfile = """1, REBECCA M. ROTH , COLLECTOR OF TAXES of the taxing district of the
township of MORRIS for Six Hundred Sixty Seven dollars andFifty Two cents, the land
in said taxing district described as Block No. 10303 Lot No. 10 :
and known as 239 E HANOVER AVE , on the tax Taxes For: 2012
Sewer

Assessments For Improvements

Total Cost of Sale 35.00
Total
Premium (if any) Paid 1,400.00 """
```

Would like to know where am i making mistake.
Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Can you brief what you are trying to match for each word with the regex (so that we can help you out for what you are expecting to do with the regex)?

Comment: @MaheshAnakali its a list of words in words variable. you can check above code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of issues:

1. As others have mentioned, you need to escape special characters like parentheses `(` `)` and dots `.`. Very simply, you can use [`re.escape`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape)
2. Another issue is the trailing space in `Premium \(if any\) Paid`  (it's trying to match two spaces instead of one as you're also checking for a space in your regex `{} ([^ ]*)`)

You should instead change your code to the following:

[See working code here](https://tio.run/##bVLBbqMwEL37K55yAVYIkdA9NNIeKCJKpbRUgKqVqq7kDWZjFWxku03Qar89HWi2l12fxvPGb@a98TC6g1bJ@ezEybWyE/iGxWKxDFHmN3mWpbiLUBb1FiGyYrfLs7ooUWxQp9/zCrqFOwg4fpLqFxppnZF7d0kzp4/KHuQw3e@Ksryt0GqDSp6wfVWNEc0UuxGVeBMKje46biy4ajaypXR91NgL5Ww4d@kIYFLBctn807IRdm/kT6LkFjed3r/gXkdYxkmcYKfd5YY1Ixa8KBptqlwl18ixTe@Lx7xE@piTTq3@ikLNT8Jio80aq3i5YpU4CsNYaq2wtp9Gm0Dc9oPRb2JOMFZrxztk2s5GVJxMTb5GcfwBsAcjevnaw5ctSR0DPEx6luFVHFPR5D5jR20aS6t48uppUN16ofcpiuKLIIr@y@Y9Myb7QRsHI9jkuQQZN7OuGeiMRG5E1ErV8K7zvd9/4D/9wPOXwIuovufOJ5g85YPwZRDQBi4fJJjfD0Yq54/B@fwO)

```
words = ['Town of','Block No.','Lot No.','Premium (if any) Paid']

import re
for i in words:
    y = re.findall('{} ([^ ]*)'.format(re.escape(i)), textfile)
    print(y)
```

Comment: I tried but it didn't work for me last word doesn't appear.

Comment: Did you click on the link to see the code running on tio? The output section contains 1400

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

1. Your current `'Premium (if any) Paid '` string ends on a space, and `'{} ([^ ]*)'` also has a space after `{}`, which adds them together. Delete the trailing space in `'Premium (if any) Paid '`.
2. You need to escape parenthesis, so if you want to keep your regular expression unchanged, the string in the list should be `['Premium \(if any\) Paid']`. You can also use `re.escape` instead.

For your particular cases, this seems to be an optimal solution:

```
words = ['Town of','Block No.','Lot No.','Premium (if any) Paid']

import re
for i in words:
    y = re.findall('{}\s+([\S]*)'.format(re.escape(i)), text, re.I)
    print(y)
```

Comment: I tried escaping parenthesis but it doesn't work. I found easy solution to remove parenthesis using .replace. but the problem is not solved yet

Comment: Have you removed the space after "Paid" in the list? Can you comment the output you get here?

Comment: Here is a [link] [https://pastebin.com/AK5TPEsU]  for raw text file that i am using and the output i get is like this: []
['30708']
['15']
['']

Comment: Well, in that case "premium (if any) paid" is in all caps. So add the `re.I` flag. Also, there is more than one space after the phrase, so you need to change your regex accordingly.

Comment: Added the working code in my answer to fit your needs.